# Avoid repeating certain html tags while rendering a jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

In the following code, `users` in an array of user objects, which have a name property in them:

```
$.template("listTemplate", "<ul><li>${name}</li></ul>");
$.tmpl("listTemplate", users).appendTo("#app");
```

My purpose is to generate a html similar to:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li>Barney</li>
    <li>Cartman</li>
    <li>Sheldon</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, I'm stuck with:

```
<div id="app">
    <ul><li>Barney</li></ul>
    <ul><li>Cartman</li></ul>
    <ul><li>Sheldon</li></ul>
</div>
```

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this directly with a `jquery` template, and somehow indicate to the templating engine that `<ul>` need not be repeated?

Comment: what plugin/library do you use to make the tempalte ? Or are you only trying to generate the html you showed ? If it is you don't realy need  a template but simple jQuery.

Comment: simple jQuery li insertion.
http://plnkr.co/edit/HYaV5NxZOQQbjnkYKF1q?p=preview